# Building a portfolio based on possible personal finance scenarios

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, portfolio

I would like to start a portfolio of assets which I don't have to manage day to day.

I don't have a specific savings goal in mind but have a number of scenarios where I might want to withdraw money.

E.g:

- In 3 years there is a 20% chance I would want to sell $10k worth of assets
- In 10 years there is 50% chance I would want to sell all the assets

Is there any sensible way to calculate what share of my portfolio should be in low/medium/high risk investments?

Is there any tool that allows me to visualize:

In 10 years there is a 90% probability that my savings will be worth more than x.

Comment: A mutual fund is a pool of investments shared by multiple people. IT sounds like you just want a portfolio, not necessarily a "mutual fund", correct?

Comment: @DStanley yes, I just don't want to invest in stocks directly